# Send With DocSign Button On Generate Document Of CPQ Quote Object

Tags: cpq, docusign

I am trying to send quote document to sales rep using **Send With DocuSign** button available on **Generate Document** For that i am using (Legacy)DocSign eSignature for CPQ and created Envelope Configuration. In Envelope Configuration I set CRL Recipient using Advance parameter as follows

Email~{!SBQQ__Quote__c.SBQQ__SalesRep__c.Email};Role~Signer;RoutingOrder~1;

But it show me empty recipient as shown in screenshot. I also use CRL parameter as

Email~{!SBQQ__Quote__r.SBQQ__SalesRep__r.Email};Role~Signer;RoutingOrder~1;

But it still show me empty.

[image]

Any suggestion & help is appreciated
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

Came across this post while trying to hunt down the exact same answer and I had to contact Docusign to resolve as nowhere in their documentation is this explained. In case another poor soul comes looking, here is the correct syntax to get the above to populate when using a CRL Advanced Parameter with Legacy Docusign v7.0+ and Docusign for CPQ v2.2.

```
Email~{!SBQQ__QuoteDocument__c.SBQQ__Quote__r.SBQQ__SalesRep__r.Email};Role~Signer;RoutingOrder~1;
```

Hope that saves someone the headache I just went through!